# How many functions have been registered by atexit()?

Tags: c, linux, exit, atexit

We met an issue that a 3rd party library registered some function(s) with `atexit()`.
Is there any way to know how many(or which) functions have been registered?

I checked [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/atexit.html) but it said no.

I tried to get `ATEXIT_MAX` with `sysconf` but it turned out to be a huge number like `2^31-1`.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: To make work what? This is just meant to be like that: you can't change it or inspect it. Every library that uses it is supposed to know exactly what it is doing and only to uses it to do clean up that cannot be achieved otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to sneak in your own `atexit()` function, effectively overriding the original and then protocol each call to that by the third-party-software.  But that probably isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This could help us to locate the problem.

Comment: @Zhongzhi, you still haven't explained what you mean by "problem".

Comment: @JensGustedt It's when the program exit() with a status code, the parent process didn't get the status code passed to exit(). So I guess it was because some 3rd party called atexit() that changed the behavior.

Comment: Did you consider stepping through it with a debugger?  There could other issues be involved which cloak an exit code.  I hate hunting ghosts ...

Comment: @Zhongzhi, such a thing should in fact not happen. It only could if one of these `atexit` functions called `exit` or even `_Exit`, but this would really be considered bad style.